# Setting up git on Linux server

Tags: linux, authentication, github, redhat, ssh-keys

I am trying to set up a git repo on a server running Linux RedHat.

I follow the instructions on Github's help page. I reach the step where the instructions tell me to ssh into git@github.com.

this gives me the following error -

```
 $ ssh -T git@github.com
 Permission denied (publickey).
```

So then I did $ ssh -vT git@github.com and get this -

```
 OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
 debug1: Reading configuration data /home/min/a/foo/.ssh/config
 debug1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to github.com [some IP] port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /home/shay/a/foo/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github2
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github2 pat OpenSSH*
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
 debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /home/min/a/foo/.ssh/known_hosts:1
 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /home/shay/a/foo/.ssh/id_rsa
 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here's where I currently am -

```
 $ pwd
 /home/min/a/foo/.ssh
```

I don't understand what's going wrong? Also, if I try to add this path by doing ssh-add, it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent".

Comment: did you generate / upload your ssh-gen key>?

Comment: Yes. I followed instructions on the github help page and I can see the second key (I have one key for my laptop already there and it works) in my keys.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you either have not uploaded a key to github, or you have uploaded a key that does not match your default key for the current user.

Check that your local key is on github:

- Get your key's fingerprint: `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Check this against the list of allowed keys on github: https://github.com/settings/ssh

Alternatively, check that your key is *enabled* on github. A little while ago, a there was an [security issue related to ssh keys on github](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation). All ssh keys were disabled in order to force users to review their list of allowed keys. If you've not used github recently, yours could still be disabled.

Comment: Don't forget to check the _permissions_ of .ssh - key authentication won't work if it is too permissive.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: This is true, but incorrect permissions (too broad or too narrow) would be indicated in the debug output (`Permissions 0777 for '/home/david/.ssh/id_dsa' are too open.` or `could not open key file '/home/david/.ssh/id_dsa': Permission denied`). That, at least, is the behavior of openssh 5.9 (the OP is using 5.3).

Comment: I didn't realize it would actually *tell* you.  Good to know!

Comment: Unfortunately neither was the case. I checked that the two keys were the same using the instructions given by vezult (thanks for your time, btw) and I made sure the permissions were changed to only read and write by me (I am in a lab group and my instructor asked to give complete access to all within the lab - I changed this for the ssh to only me). None of those worked. Same result - permission denied. I added this key recently (a few minutes before I posted the original question) so I don't believe that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is interested or has a similar issue and checks this post, the solution is to cd out of the .ssh dir and ssh into github. Provided everything else is followed exactly as on github's help page, this will solve the problem.